# Index match on 2D array inside VBA

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

This is not the usual case where the array is defined within Excel.
It is defined within VBA, and I need to find the proper value given a value found in a cell in Excel.
In cell A1 I have the value DE000C5RQDA9. In B1 I want to return RXM1.

The actual array is more of a (0 to 9, 0 to XX) so do not think a dictionary is feasible. XX changes dynamically.

Example

```
 Sub Test()

 Dim arr(0 To 1, 0 To 1)
 arr(0,0) = "RXM1"
 arr(0,1) = "UBM1"
 arr(1,0) = "DE000C5RQDA9"
 arr(1,1) = "DE000C5RQDD3"
 
With Application
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = .Index(arr(0), .Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1), arr(1), 0))
End with

 End sub
```

Comment: Firstly, `arr(0)` and `arr(1)` have no meaning for a 2D array. Then, you tried a code for an array with two rows and two columns. What the code should return for an array having 9 rows and 10 columns, supposing that the vale in `Cells(1, 2)` matches the one in column 4, row 3?

Comment: The idea is you can match a value in a 1D array. The good news is you can slice rows or columns in a 2D array, making them 1D arrays and (if want only using Index - Match) try matching (only) between the two such columns. This means that you must know what columns to match for the case of more than two columns in the array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Application.Index to get the columns you want to use in the INDEX/MATCH.

The same idea could be used for rows.

```
Sub Test()
Dim arr(0 To 1, 0 To 1)
Dim col1 As Variant
Dim col2 As Variant

    arr(0, 0) = "RXM1"
    arr(0, 1) = "UBM1"
    arr(1, 0) = "DE000C5RQDA9"
    arr(1, 1) = "DE000C5RQDD3"

    col1 = Application.Index(arr, 1)
    col2 = Application.Index(arr, 2)
    With Application
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2) = .Index(col1, .Match(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), col2))
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ... or `... = .Index(Arr, .Match(Tabelle2.Cells(1, 1), col2), 1)` avoiding at least the 1st column slice :-)